Why do I need a empty window.attributes() to create a transparent window using tkinter (in python)?
When I create a transparent window with tkinter in python I need to start with a empty window.attributes() call.Otherwise it doesn't become transparent. Is this a bug or wanted behavior ?
Example code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.attributes() # Unless I use this line the window will not be transparent
window.attributes('-alpha', 0.5)
window.update_idletasks()
window.mainloop()

Other things I noticed:

Making it wait a bit between the creation of the window and making it transparent does not help.By using time.sleep(1) instead of window.attributes()
The window.attributes() has to be empty. Setting another attribute does not help.e.g.: window.attributes("-fullscreen", True) instead of window.attributes().
Surprisingly the the empty window.attributes() is not necessary when I want to change another attribute.e.g.: window.attributes("-fullscreen", True) will  create a full screen window with or without starting with window.attributes()

My system:

Mint 22 (A Linux distro based on Ubuntu 24.04)
Python from Ubuntu package python3 version 3.12.3-0ubuntu2
Tkinter from Ubuntu package python3-tk version 3.12.3-0ubuntu1
X server from Ubuntu package xserver-xorg-core version 2:21.1.12-1ubuntu1
Cinnamon as desktop environment from Mint package cinnamon version 6.2.9+wilma
Tk from Ubuntu package tk version 8.6.14build1

I also wonder if this behavior happens on other systems...

I think the issue is that the window is not ready for the alpha option.  Calling window.update_idletasks() instead of window.attributes() can also fix the issue.  Or delay the setting of alpha option a bit using window.after(...).

This is not a bug. Tk behaves differently on different platforms in some cases.

On both my Raspberry Pi and Windows 11 systems the window becomes transparent without the parameter-less window.attributes() line.
This problem is likely your system. If your computer is slow while running normal tasks (e.g. a web browser) that could be what is causing the need for the no-parameter window.attributes() call.
However, the call without parameters shouldn't impact performance, so if it's what works for you, I recommend you continue the way you're working around the issue.

OP is using Ubuntu 22.04 not Window 11.

That's why I said that it's probably OP's computer and not an error on OP's part.

Performance should not be the issue. It's not too slow because I tried it on a new system that's barely doing anything and it's not too fast because i also tried emulating that with the sleep call

Okay, well if the empty call is working for you, continuing to use that method of circumvention isn't harmful so maybe just keep doing things that way.
